# Choose Different Payment Method on Cancel with PayPal

Tags: jsp, paypal, message, cart

I am using JSP and have just integrated Paypal with my shopping cart. Would anyone know how I can serve a custom message should a customer use Paypal, then decide to cancel the transaction and return to my store to use a different payment method?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I can't find what I am looking for in the PayPal API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the CancelURL to whatever you want, so you could add some URL parameter or something like &canceled=true, and then display a message based on whether or not that URL parameter is included.